# Node.js EventEmitter handler memory leak

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks

Is this a memory leak?

```
class Leaky {
    constructor(options) {
        process.on('message', function(msg) {
            this.do_something(msg)
            // ...
        }.bind(this))
    }

    // ...
}
```

When I call `new Leaky()` a reference is bound to the instance through the handler. `process` is not going to be GC'd, so did I just leak the `Leaky` instance?

How can I prevent this? The only solution I can think of is having a `dispose` method that calls `process.off`, but I'd like to avoid that. I don't see something like `unref` or weak handlers on `EventEmitter`.

Comment: Do you need to add a new event handler for each instance of `Leaky`? Could you store a list of `Leaky`s and have one handler that operates on that list? It would make it easier to remove the event handler when you don't have any more instances to work against.

Comment: Yes, this would prevent your instances from getting garbage collected. Does every instance of Leaky listen for the exact same message?  If so, I can think of a different way to implement this that doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Why are you using both an arrow function and `.bind(this)`  Pick one or the other.

Comment: @MikeCluck In the actual code it's not `process` but another long lived `EventEmitter` that is passed in the options. I thought about the indirection (only register one handler and execute from a list of handlers) but it does not solve the memory leak problem: in the end there has to be a list of handlers that reference every instance. I looked at WeakMap and WeakSet but they are not enumerable.

Comment: @Fozi What exactly is the event emitter if it is not `process`? What are the `Leaky` entities, and how many are there (do they accumulate over time or is the number limited)? Also if the `Leaky` ones are supposed to be shorter-lived than the event emitter, when exactly does their live end (i.e. when are they no longer needed)?

Comment: @Bergi it's a distributed event emitter [like this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/distributed-eventemitter), and the lifetime is a long running workflow item on a clustered server instance.